# How to modify outgoing URLs that are opening in new tabs

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to add parameters to clicks on outgoing links. So for example something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/outgoing/"]').forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.target.href += "?param=this";
}, false));
```

And this works fine for clicks on links that don't have target="_blank". Links that open in a new tab, the new tab opens before the href is edited. Is there a way to modify the outgoing URL in links that open in a new tab? How is that even handled? Where can I learn about how that works?

Comment: Modify links on page load, not when clicking on them. Or have fake links, that will call your method first and then you redirect to external link

Comment: How about using [event preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to avoid <a> open a link automatically, and then you can hack and open a tab with your custom url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you just need to call `preventDefault` on the event object, then call the `window.open` method passing in the correct `target` attribute if it exists.

e.g. (commented for clarity)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/outgoing/"]')
  .forEach(i => i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // stop the event navigation
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // get the anchor element
    const ele = e.currentTarget;
    // find the target attribute if it exists
    const target = ele.hasAttribute('target') ?
        ele.getAttribute('target') : 
        null;
    // open the modified link using the target
    window.open(ele.href + "?param=this", target);
  }, false));
```

```html
<a href="/outgoing/1231" target="_blank">my link</a>
```

For `preventDefault` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

For `window.open` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open